# Change value in URL without affecting history

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am pretty sure I am failing to find an answer to this just because I am not using the correct terminology when googling.

In my website I want to display some details about the user's state like selections or filters in the URL so it can be copied and sent to a colleague to replicate the state somewhere else. However, I don't want to enter a state in the history for each change to this so that the back buttons and refresh are affected. I want to make it so that if you navigate to a new place within the website or if you press back/forward/refresh in your browser, the extra parameters (to the extent I chose) will be discarded.

Whenever I try to google for this the topics are always "Change url without reloading page" where I want "Change url text superficially without affecting ANY behavior of the history or browser".

I am developing with GWT so I anticipate that a javascript approach will be most appropriate.

Comment: location.replace

Comment: https://w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Comment: @RatajS Doesnt location.replace change the most recent or current history token to the new value? I want to change the url text while leaving the history completely unchanged.

Comment: You can't change the URL without affecting the browser history. But you can replace the last entry in the browser history using `history.replaceState()` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

Comment: Ok so you can't change the url text without affecting the history... How do websites get the effect where adding stuff to your cart, or opening subfolders adds parameters to the url, but if you press the back button, you are redirected to the revious place, not to the last state of the parameter change?